# Node.js Webshot not working with PowerBI, because WebGL is not supported by Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, powerbi

This question (sort of) comes as a follow up to [this SO question from awhile back.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978216/5000465)

I have already successfully installed and tested Webshot.js - and it actually works great! On everything except its designated purpose. I am taking a screenshot of public/published PowerBI reports. They are blank. Always.

My code:

```
webshot('https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=ReallyLongURLKey', 
    './workdammit.png', function(err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Screenshot taken!');
});
```

I've messed with the settings plenty, allowing a very lengthy renderDelay, error handling, screen size tweaks, everything. Nothing worked, and the best result I could get was a hard-coded footer minus all the graphic stuff I actually wanted.

[image: The image, all blank save the footer.]

I was lost until I came across the StackOverflow question I linked at the top. Webshot.js is based on Phantom.js, which does not support WebGL. Guess what PowerBI uses to render their graphs. **WebGL**.

I'd like to take a page out of the kellyfelkins playbook, but I am unsure how to handle this work-around, or even where to start, as our problems and starting points are not exactly the same.

Is there a way to "force" a screenshot anyway, for lack of a better term? Maybe feed Webshot a setting that mimics a compliant web page? Use a different library altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the form of [node-server-screenshot.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-server-screenshot) It has many of the same settings that affect render delay, scale, size, and quality, and works with PowerBI and other web services that utilize WebGL.

As an example, a chunk of code may look like this.

```
    var app = require('../Node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-server-screenshot/index.js');
app.fromURL("https://yahoo.com", "E:/Website/Test.png", 
     { clip: {width: 1600, height: 900 }, scale: 1, waitMilliseconds: 10000, timeout: 60000 }, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```